# React condition rendering component typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, conditional-statements, conditional-rendering

I have a component called Visible with two props: condition and children
the flow is if the condition is true the component will return the children(s) and if not it will return null (just like condition rendering), but VScode doesn't recognized that what the condition is doing and throw an error for children (the variable may be null)

is there a way to define a type for this component return that VScode recognizes the condition checks the variables?

Visible.ts:

```
interface IVisible {
    condition: any
    children: React.ReactNode
}

function Visible(props: IVisible) : React.ReactNode {
    const {condition, children} = props

    if( !(!!condition) ) return null;
    
    return <Fragment>{children}</Fragment>
}
```

usage ex:

```
const [banana, setBanana] = useState<undefined|string[]>(["foo","bar"])

return (
    <Visible condition={banana}>
        <ul>
        {banana.map(e => <li key={e}>{e}</li>) }
        </ul>
    </Visible>
)
```

Comment: It will be easier for you to figure out the problem if your `condition` prop is `boolean`, as it should be.

Then you can just think about how to convert that array to a boolean before passing it as a prop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this! Declare return type is JSX.Element

```
interface IVisible {
    condition: boolean;
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Visible = ({ condition, children }: IVisible): JSX.Element =>
    condition ? <Fragment>{children}</Fragment> : null;
```

But I still recommend using just conditional rendering.

I don’t understand why to make a component when there is an already implemented opportunity for this.

When there are additional calculations or some other peculiarities, then yes, you can make a component.

But when you just need to render a component by a simple condition, it seems to me that you shouldn't make an additional component for this.

```
const [banana, setBanana] = useState<string[]>(['foo', 'bar']);

return (
    <div>
        banana.length > 0 && (
            <ul>
                {banana.map(e => (
                    <li key={e}>{e}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        )
    </div>
);
```

Comment: thanks, I understand about additional calculations and peculiarities, but each project has its own situation, creating a conditional rendering component instead of using `{condition ? : null}` helps code reading in a large project (especially in large groups), so sometimes you can pay more for better and cleaner code reading

Comment: @msaba Ok, yes I agree, it makes sense for readability of the code. Now, I understand your intent. Good coding and good luck :)

Comment: @msaba Did you get the error after changing the type to JSX.Element?

Comment: no it's fine by me